# $\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} }$ as infimum of a sequence of lower semi-continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, semicontinuous-functions

I have been trying to construct a sequence of lower semi-continuous functions that will give indicator function as the infimum. In particular, I need a sequence $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ of lsc functions such that $\inf f_n(x)=1$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and $\inf f_n(x)=0$ for $x\in\mathbb{Q}$.

I taught $f_n(x)=1/n$ when $x$ is rational and $f_n(x)=1$ otherwise. However, this function is not lsc at irrational numbers. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you tell me why the functions $f_n$ in my answer are not lower semi-continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(r_n)$ be an ennumeration of ratinal numbers and $f_n(x)=1$ if $x \neq r_n$, $f_n(x)=0$ if $x = r_n$. Then each $f_n$ is l.s.c. and $\inf_n f_n(x)=1_{\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q}(x)$ for all $x$. (I have used the fact that indicator function of any  open set is l.s.c.).

Comment: Your example is wrong because $f_n$ is not lsc

Comment: What makes you think so? If $U$ is any open set then $\chi_A$ is lower semi-continuous (where $\chi_A(x)=1$ if $x \in U$ and $0$ otherwise). This is because $\{x: \chi_A(x) >a\}$ is either $U$ or the whole space, so it is open. I am taking $U$ to be the complement of  a singleton set , so my sets are open. @user64066

Comment: $A$ is same as $U$ in above comment.

Comment: If $f_n$ was lsc on $\mathbb{R}$ then $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f_n(x)>1/2\}$ would be an open set. But this means that $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is open. This is not correct. That is why the function is not lsc.

Comment: @user64066 You are not reading the definition of $f_n$ correctly. To define $f_n$ I **fix** $n$. The definition depends only on particular rational number, namely $r_n$. So $f_n(x) >\frac 1 2 $ iff $x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{r_n\}$, the complement of  a singleton set, not the complement of the set of all rational numbers. .

Comment: @user64066 If you downvoted my answer earlier you can consider upvoting it now. Thanks for the approval.

Comment: Unfortunately it would not allow any change. If you could make a minor change then I will sure upvote it.

Comment: @user64066 I just added a lie. Thanks for your cooperation.